# Concise state machine design in R

Tags: r

I'm searching for a more matrix/apply oriented way to code a state machine in R vs what I've done here with a for loop and a bunch of if statements? Is this possible in R where you need to know the previous state of the machine?

The following machine is armed when A1 and A2 are both 1, and if armed is disarmed when B1 & B2 are both 1. In general there is no known relationship between A1, A2, B1 & B1. If none of the conditions are met then the previous state remains.

Is it possible to do this sort of calculation in R without the for loop stepping through the matrix 1 by 1? If so please create some code that calculates S1a. Thanks.

[[Edited to simplify a bit]]

```
Mach1 = matrix(data=0, nrow = 24, ncol = 6)
colnames(Mach1)=c("A1","A2","B1","B2","S1","S1a")
Mach1[,"A1"] <- c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
Mach1[,"A2"] <- c(0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

Mach1[,"B1"] <- c(0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0)
Mach1[,"B2"] <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1)

for (i in 2:nrow(Mach1)){
  Prev = Mach1[(i-1),"S1"]
  Prev = ifelse(is.na(Prev), 0, Prev)
  Arm = ((Mach1[i,"A1"] ==1) && (Mach1[i,"A2"] == 1))
  Disarm = ((Mach1[i,"B1"] == 1) && (Mach1[i,"B2"] == 1))

  if ((Prev == 0) && (Arm)){ #Turn on
    Mach1[i,"S1"] <- 1
    print(paste(i, "Armed"))
  } else  if ((Prev == 1) && (Disarm)){ #Turn off
    Mach1[i,"S1"] <- 0
    print(paste(i, "Disarmed"))
  } else {
    Mach1[i,"S1"] <- Prev
    print(paste(i, "---"))
  }
}

rm(Arm, Disarm, Prev, i)
```

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/9126/implement-state-machine-pattern-using-s4-class) you can find a general approach for using state machine pattern via S4 classes under R.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With package `zoo` you can use this:

```
on <- with(as.data.frame(Mach1), A1 & A2)
off <- with(as.data.frame(Mach1), B1 & B2)

na.locf(c(1,0)[(!off) + 2*(!on)], na.rm=FALSE)
```

Result

```
[1] NA NA NA NA NA  1  1  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

Just replace the `NA` at the beginning with the initial machine state.

Comment: Thanks Ferdinand. This is a really interesting solution which works nicely. I'm having trouble getting my head around why I have to cast the matrix as a data.frame (which does appear necessary) but other than  that it's exactly the simple sort of solution that I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure how to post code in a comment correctly but this gets rid of the as.data.frame and seems to work for me. The 'S1b' name doesn't match the original matrix so anyone trying it could adjust that.         Mach1[,"on1"] <- ((Mach1[,"A1"]) & (Mach1[,"A2"]))
Mach1[,"off1"] <- ((Mach1[,"B1"]) & (Mach1[,"B2"]))

Mach1[,"S1b"] = na.locf(c(1,0)[(!Mach1[,"off1"]) + 2*(!Mach1[,"on1"])], na.rm=FALSE)
Mach1[,"S1b"] = na.fill(Mach1[,"S1b"],0)

Comment: This is an interesting solution, I am still trying to understand it, but it works for this particular case. In this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/9126/implement-state-machine-pattern-using-s4-class) you can find a general approach for using state machine pattern via S4 classes.